# Property FillFactor set and is not supported when used as part of data package when deploying to Azure from SSMS

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have a SQL 2014 database that I am trying to deploy to Azure V12.

I have read in numerous places (most notably here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/158501/remove-index-fillfactor-for-azure-migration) that Fill Factor is now supported on Azure V12. Yet, I am not finding this to be the case.

I still receive many "*Property FillFactor set and is not supported...*" errors when attempting to deploy the database to Azure SQL Server, using Sql Server Management Studio (SSMS).

I have tried setting the Fill Factor on the first few indexes listed in the error message to 0, manually in SSMS. This works in that errors relating to those indexes disappear. I have too many indexes to fix - and it is likely I will need to do this for other databases in the future - to use SSMS to manually alter all indexes.

I have also tried using a the script found here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16542679/5019) to adjust all the fill factors to 0, however that fails with the error "Fillfactor 0 is not a valid percentage; fillfactor must be between 1 and 100".

Am I missing a setting or option somewhere that will allow me to deploy databases with indexes containing Fill Factors, to Azure V12?

If not, is there a way I can set the Fill Factors on all indexes to 0?

Comment: Have you downloaded the latest SSMS? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms

Comment: Remember fill factor 0 and 100 are the same. Use 100. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46059/how-can-a-fill-factor-of-0-or-100-be-the-same

Comment: Yes! You are right @AlbertoMorillo - I had not paid attention to the version of SSMS. Using version 17.3 works.. Thank you. If you'd like to write that up as an answer I'd be happy to accept (and upvote!)

Comment: I am glad to know it is working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please upgrade to the latest version of SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) for the best user experience with Azure. You can download it from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms).